# Suppose I have an isomorphism $f:P_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and it satisfies..

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have an isomorphism $f:P_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and it satisfies..

$f(t^2 + t) = (1,1,0)$

$f(t + 1) = (2,0,1)$

$f(t − 1) = (3,1,2)$

Use this information to find $f(t^2 + t + 1)$.

I know that isomorphisms preserve linear combinations, but what is the matrix that I would set up and solve??

Comment: What is $P_{2}$?

Comment: I would assume it is the space of degree two polynomials.

Comment: all that was given to me was that, could it be an arbitrary equation at^2+bt+c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$t^2 + t + 1 = (t^2 + t) + \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ (t + 1) - (t - 1) \right]$

This is a linear combination of the points given. Now apply $f$ to it.